# static application for iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios

What I want is to create iPhone application.

Everything will be static data. What I want is show menu (as Menu 1, Menu 2, ...) one by one at the down side. Once I click on Menu 1, I will display details of Menu 1 on next screen.

Right now what  I have done is created home page. There I have button saying Menu. Once I click on that button, I am going to another screen which is TableViewController. Any idea how to show menu buttons there?

Any idea or suggestion would be greatful.

Thanks in advance to all...

Comment: Do you wanna use Objective C or PhoneGap?

Comment: the easier way is to use Interface Builder to place the elements on the screen. After that connect the IBOutlet to interact with the actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are looking for `UITabBarController`, check the [reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).
If you don't want use the `UITabBarController` you could insert your "home page" controller into a [UINavigationController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and push your viewcontrollers with some `IBAction` associated to your buttons, or otherwise display your controllers in modal way.